# Go back to earlier ZFS configuration

Tags: zfs

My ZFS array was in Z10, (Two striped mirrored pair)

```
    NAME                                          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    mythtv    
      mirror-0                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD20EZRX-00D8PB0_WD-WCC4MKTE0Z6D  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD20EARX-00PASB0_WD-WCAZAJ097805  ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-1                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD20EZRZ-00Z5HB0_WD-WCC4M5NCCE13  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD20EZRZ-00Z5HB0_WD-WCC4M3ETCDKX  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

And a disk had a error.
In state of making a `zpool replace "old disk" "new disk"` I made the mistake of doing `zpool remove "old disk"` and `zpool add "new disk"`

And now I have this strange configuration

```
    NAME                                          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    mythtv                                        ONLINE       0     0     0
      ata-WDC_WD20EZRX-00D8PB0_WD-WCC4MKTE0Z6D    ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-1                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD20EZRZ-00Z5HB0_WD-WCC4M5NCCE13  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD20EZRZ-00Z5HB0_WD-WCC4M3ETCDKX  ONLINE       0     0     0
      ata-WDC_WD20EARX-00PASB0_WD-WCAZAJ862597    ONLINE       0     0     0
```

How can I go back to the original z10 ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714527/removing-disk-from-zfs-pool-permanently  The ability to remove a disk is highly relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no you can't do that. You have two options:

1) Add 2 more disks in order to make each of the standalone vdevs a mirror

2) Create a new pool of required configuration and migrate the data to it, and then reclaim the disks from the old pool. Or do a full backup, re-create the pool, and restore the backup.